# mysql - join. only show result if all values match the where statement

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables:
Table 1

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Table 2

| idtable1 | show |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Y |
| 1 | Y |
| 2 | Y |
| 2 | N |

I want my query to only show the id when all 'show' are Y.
if run following query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.idtable1 WHERE table2.show = Y
```

this will give me this result

| id | idtable1 | show |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | Y |
| 2 | 2 | Y |

but I want this as a result

| id | idtable1 | show |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | Y |

Comment: There's no table1 in your query

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the ids of `table1` with this query:

```
SELECT idtable1 FROM table2 GROUP BY idtable1 HAVING MIN(show) = 'Y'
```

So your query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.id = t2.idtable1 
WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT idtable1 FROM table2 GROUP BY idtable1 HAVING MIN(show) = 'Y')
```

Although, if you need only the `id` from `table1` there is no need for the join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
WHERE idtable1 IN (SELECT idtable1 FROM table2 GROUP BY idtable1 HAVING MIN(show) = 'Y')
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2 t 
  WHERE t.idtable1 = t2.idtable1 AND t.show = 'N'
)
```

I assume there are no `null`s in the column `show`.